# Format column csv from export php-mysqli

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

The code below exports a .csv file with multiple columns. The column "PRET" is General formatted and it contains the price of products with format `xx.xx` . I want to turn my values in `xx,xx`. How can I format the column PRET of type Text or should I replace "." with "," when the file is exported?

```
<?php
// call export function
exportMysqlToCsv('export_stoc.csv');

// export csv
function exportMysqlToCsv($filename = 'export_stoc.csv')
{
$conn = dbConnection();
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//v

$sql_query = "SELECT
      produse.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F,
      stoc.CANTITATE,
      produse.PRET,
      produse.VALUTA,
      stare.STARE
FROM clase
JOIN produse ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN furnizori ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
JOIN stoc ON stoc.ID_PRODUS = produse.ID
JOIN stare ON stare.ID = stoc.ID_STARE;
     //execute this sql and fetch your results as needed

// Gets the data from the database
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);
$f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
$first = true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         if ($first) {
                 fputcsv($f, array_keys($row), ';')
                 $first = false;
         }
         fputcsv($f, $row, ';');
} // end while

$conn->close();
$size = ftell($f);
rewind($f);
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: $size");
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
fpassthru($f);
exit;
}
// db connection function
function dbConnection(){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bd";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
return $conn;
}

?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are no "formats" in CSV; CSV is just plain-text separated by some separator.

So...

> should I replace "." with "," when the file is exported.

...yes.

Comment: Will this not add another Comma into a Comma Seperated File. That might be a Bad Idea

Comment: Well, yes, if you actually use commas to separate. Other separators are commonly used, like semicolons or tabulators. Alternatively, you can try to put your values in quotation marks to prevent the comma from being recognized as separators; it depends on the capabilities of the program that parses your output.

Comment: I need to format the text column, replacing the comma do in excel

Comment: If the target is Excel take a look at the `phpExcel` library. With that you can set the formatting of a column. And actually write `.xlsx` files rather than `csv` format files

Comment: I tried to export the first time in .xlsx but we had errors (corrupt file) and I preferred to export .csv. The simplest option remains my column in text format.

Comment: I tried many options, we added the code:
`$ ObjPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;`
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);` but not working. Error is: _Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\export_stoc\export_stoc.php:48 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\export_stoc\export_stoc.php(3): exportMysqlToCsv('export_stoc.csv') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\export_stoc\export_stoc.php on line 48_